# In typescript, can I parameterise 'base' generic types?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following type, which checks whether the parameter T matches an expected type then returns a new type based on its inferred type parameter:

```
type Match<T> = (T extends Expected<infer U> ? NewType<U> : never)
```

In this case, I want to be able to switch out Expected and NewType and re-use this pattern, assuming they will always have the same shape, that of a single type parameter.

So my ideal would be something like:

```
type Expected<T> = {}
type NewType<T> = {}

type Match<T, E, N> = (T extends E<infer U> ? N<U> : {})

// Could be used like:
type Matcher<T> = Match<T, Expected, NewType>;
```

But this fails, ´Type E is not generic´, same with N. Obviously.

I was wondering if there's a roundabout way to achieve something like this...?

Is there a proper term for this pattern and this 'base' generic type?

Edit:
Comment confirmed that HKTs are applicable in this case.

I'm using 'fp-ts' (I suck at it) - can anyone explain how I could use its HKT implementation to solve my use case? The documentation just talks about functors... https://grossbart.github.io/fp-ts-recipes/#/hkt

Comment: These are called higher kinded types and currently not supported in TS, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213

Comment: I stumbled across HKTs looking for answers, but couldn't wrap my head around them enough to tell whether they were appropriate to this. Thanks for clarifying! Any idea how I might implement the above using the HKT implementation in 'fp-ts'?

Comment: HKT means you can pass functions at type level - `Expected` isnt a type, it is a function with one argument `T`. TS is not supports passing type function around, so it doesnt support higher order function at type level, and this is exactly HKT

Comment: 'Expected isn't a type, it is a function with one argument T'... so the way to think of an HKT could be as a function that produces a Type?

Comment: HKT is more higher order function, generic type is a function, take this read to see how I see the whole type system - https://dev.to/macsikora/typescript-is-more-than-you-think-2nbf